# Faceted graph with different colors for by(group)

Tags: stata

I have two categorical variables, `industry` and `province`, for individuals in my dataset. To create a faceted graph that allows me to see how many individuals work in an industry for each province, I am using the following code:

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/nlsw88.dta
twoway (histogram industry), by(occupation)
```

Because I have around 20 provinces, I would like to colorize each province in `by(province)` differently. I have tried using `twoway (graph bar industry, over(province)` to no avail.
Is it possible in Stata to color each province differently?

Answer (score 0):

`twoway graph bar` is illegal and `graph bar industry` by itself would at best show the means of a numerical variable `industry`.

The ideal graph to show frequencies of `industry` by `province` might depend on how many distinct values of `industry` there were; you say 20 distinct values of `province`.

There is no data example here, so it is hard to guess, but `tabplot` from the *Stata Journal* allows both plotting frequencies from a two-way table and different colours.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out! I have also added the data example from the Stata Forum.